# insertAfterMso="GroupAlignmentExcel" in xml file doesn't work

Tags: excel, xml, user-interface, ribbon

I'm trying to add a button to excel's ribbon Home tab. It seems like this section from the xml file:

```
insertAfterMso="GroupAlignmentExcel"
```

doesn't work, because the group end up at the end on the tab.

Full xml code:

```
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui">
    <ribbon>
        <tabs>
            <tab idMso="TabHome" >
                <group id="CenterAll" label=" ">
                    <button id="CenterAllButton" label="Center All" onAction="CenterAll" imageMso="TableCellAlignMiddleCenter" size="large" insertAfterMso="GroupAlignmentExcel" />
                </group>
            </tab>
        </tabs>
    </ribbon>
</customUI>
```

Does anyone know what could be my problem?

Does this code works for you?